# Написание программы под Linux (Orange Pi)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, библиотеки, orange-pi

Добрый день. Необходимо написать программу, которая будет запускаться в Debian на устройстве Orange Pi. Основной код мне дали. Для начала, решил добиться его работоспособности в Windows. Подключил к проекту библиотеки curl, а так же libcrypto и libssl. Всё заработало, теперь необходимо добиться аналогичного в Debian. Студия тут уже, как я понимаю, не подходит. Буду писать в Qt. Вопросы вот в чем: 
 
На сайте curl при скачивании библиотеки целевой платформой выбрал Debian, в итоге был скачан файл .deb. Как я понимаю, им можно проинсталлировать библиотеку непосредственно в систему, но не подключить в проект (причем на странице скачивания говорилось, что лучше устанавливать не им, а непосредственно из консоли системы). Как тогда подключить эту библиотеку к Qt? С остальными либами, полагаю поступать придется так же.
Как вообще в дальнейшем компилировать код в приложение под linux? Никогда прежде подобным не занимался. Я пока погуглю, разумеется, но может чей-то ответ мне сэкономит много времени.

Answer (score 2):

В целом, как и в Windows...
Устанавливаете необходимые пакеты - компилятор, IDE, либы и их хедеры.

`apt install qtcreator curl libcrypto++6 libcrypto++-dev libssl1.1 libssl-dev cpp`

(пакеты, имена которых заканчиваются суффиксом "-dev" содержат *.h файлы и исходный код)

Answer (score 0):

Добавление библиотеки в QtCreator осуществляется правкой .pro файла CMakeLists.txt в каталоге проекта.
Про синтаксис файла можно почитать в https://habrahabr.ru/post/155467/

Или же можно прописать библиотеки в параметрах проекта в опциях сборки.

Answer (score -6):

Самый лучший способ экономии времени - это нанять человека, который хоть что-нибудь понимает в том, что надо сделать. Но у нас время человека ничего не стоит, потому задания даются не тем, кто их может выполнить, а тому, чье время ничего не стоит. И самое обидное тут то, что тот, чье время ничего не стоит, охотно берется за работу, поддерживая тем самым этот порядок.

Библиотеки бывают двух видов: для рантайма (что-то запустить) и для разработки (заголовочные файлы + архивы символов с которыми можно слинковаться). Для этого в дебиане почти для каждого пакета библиотеки есть ее брат-близнец с суффиксом -dev, что намекает на "для девелоперов".

Qt, некая "студия" или очередное крутое IDE с зеленой кнопочкой "запустить" совершенно не обязательно, код можно писать в любом текстовом редактора вроде блокнота. Правда придется выучить, как же эта "волшебная зеленая кнопка" собирает код и превращает его в бинарник - это гораздо сложнее. Например, в линуксе часто используется automake, который часто и запускается из IDE. Если не нравится - есть другие системы сборки. Выбор - это одна из ключевых особенностей линукса.

Когда приложение будет закончено, то для его компиляции, как и с практически любым приложением, надо будет запустить лишь команду `make`, быть может, после скрипта конфигурации `./configure`

Но еще лучше не "писать в Qt", а хотя бы попробовать разобраться в том, что же это такое "Qt", а лучше прямо сказать: "эта работа не по моему профилю, я не буду ее делать".